# Fourier transform on time integral

Tags: fourier-transform

We define the Fourier transformation as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-iwt}dt=\hat{f}(w)
$$
If we apply the Fourier transformation on
$$
\int_{\Omega}\int_0^{\infty}f(x,t)dtdx
$$
by definition is
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-iwt}(\int_{\Omega}\int_0^{\infty}f(x,t)dtdx)dt
$$
which if we switch the order of integration becomes
$$
\int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-iwt}( \int_0^{\infty}f(x,t)dt)dt dx
$$
I am thinking of pulling the exponential into the most inner integration which gives
$$
\int_{\Omega} \int_0^{\infty}\hat{f}(w,x)dtdx
$$
but this does not make sense given the inner integration goes to infinity.

Or if we take
$$
F(x) = \int_0^{\infty}f(x,t)dt
$$
then the Fourier transform of a 'constant' goes to a delta function(transforming on t only not considering x) then the whole thing reduces to
$$
\int_{\Omega} \delta(x-F(x))dx
$$

Comment: Notice that fourier transofrm is definied in that way only for $L^1$ functions. 
$\int_\Omega\int_0^\infty f(x,t)dtdx$ and $F(x)$ are not $L^1$ functions in time and your calculations don't make sense. Their Fourier transform can be defined only using ditribution theory

Comment: yes, that's where the delta function comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is ambiguous. If I understand you well, you want to determine the Fourier transform of the quantity $\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}x \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t \,f(x,t)$. Yet it is not a function, because $x$ and $t$ are the variables of integration and don't have any meaning outside the two integrals. In consequence, it is just a constant and its Fourier transform is given by a Dirac delta, more precisely :
$$
\mathfrak{F}\left[\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}x \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t \,f(x,t)\right](\omega) 
   = \int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{d}\tau \,e^{-i\omega\tau} \int_\Omega\mathrm{d}x \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t \,f(x,t) = 2\pi\delta(\omega) \int_\Omega\mathrm{d}x \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}t \,f(x,t)
$$

Comment: no, I am supposed to integrate $f$ under both t and x. they are not dummy variables.

Comment: @79999   Sorry, wrong translation, it's now corrected.

Comment: you didn't understand the problem. you cannot take f out of the integral.

Comment: @79999  $f$ is not outside the integral, that's a standard *notation* for multiple integrals to keep things clean $-$ perhaps more common in physics than in mathematics. And you didn't understand my point : you can't take the Fourier transform with respect to a variable of integration, but only to a free variable.

Comment: i see. so in your last equation, that f is still in side the integral. But then the dirac function you have is only about when $\omega=0$ or not. it has nothing to do with the value of the integral. or is that another notation thing?

Comment: In fact, $A = \int_\Omega \int_0^\infty f(x,t) \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}t = const$ is constant because they are definite integrals, so that its Fourier transform is given by $\int_\mathbb{R} Ae^{-i\omega\tau} \,\mathrm{d}\tau = A\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-i\omega\tau} \,\mathrm{d}\tau = A\delta(\omega)$.